# Why is the smallest example of an admissible set hereditarily finite set

Tags: set-theory

As the title says, why is the smallest example of an admissible set hereditarily finite set?

Comment: What does "admissible" mean for you here? Wikipedia gives [one definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_set) of which it says that the smallest admissible set _at all_ is the set of _all_ hereditary finite sets, which is not itself finite.

Comment: @hwe: is it possible to add further clarification to your question and make it clearer or more specific? Regards

Comment: @hwe Could you please clarify your question?

Answer (score 4):

Whether you include this in the standard formulation of Kripke-Platek set theory $\mathsf{KP}$, or consider it part of logic, "there is a set" holds (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/278872/462)), so no admissible set (that is, no model of $\mathsf{KP}$) is empty.

But then, by $\Sigma_0$-separation, there is an empty set.

Repeated application of pairing gives us now that any admissible set has as elements 
 $$ \emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},\{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\},\dots $$
and arguing with extensionality shows that all these sets are different.

It follows that no model of $\mathsf{KP}$ can be finite, much less hereditarily finite.

If what you meant to ask is why the set $V_\omega=HF$ of all hereditarily finite sets is a model of $\mathsf{KP}$ without infinity, perhaps asking it as a different question is more appropriate. When the axiom of infinity is considered as well, the smallest admissible set is $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$, where $\omega_1^{CK}$, the Church-Kleene ordinal, is the smallest [non-recursive ordinal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Kleene_ordinal).