# Are these two mathematical objects the same from a practical standpoint, or literally identical mathematical objects?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, terminology, real-numbers, integers

This question is derived from [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2637069/n-dimensional-integer-space-or-mathbfx-in-mathbbrn-x-1-x-2) that I recently asked.

Take the two mathematical objects $\{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ and $\{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{Z}^n \mid x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. If I'm interpreting his response correctly, Travis said in the comments of the previous question that these two are the same **iff** we put the addition operator on the latter (since, unless $\mathbb{R}^n$, it doesn't have a natural vector space structure). Assuming we put the addition operator on $\{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{Z}^n \mid x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$, does this mean that the two mathematical objects $\{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ and $\{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{Z}^n \mid x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ are identical from a *practical* standpoint, or are they literally identical *mathematical objects* (from the perspective of mathematical rigour and precision)?

It seems to me that they would be identical from a *practical* standpoint, but would still be different *mathematical objects*, no? So from a rigorous/precise mathematical perspective, they wouldn't be considered identical?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this. Also, please note that I have not studied abstract algebra yet, so more elementary language is appreciated.

Comment: Why work with $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{Z}^n$? The question remains the same in one dimension

Comment: "practical" ? If they satisfies the same axioms/theorems they are the same.

Comment: These two objects are sets so they are identical (or rather, equal) iff they have the same elements. Here they clearly have the same elements (assuming as usual $\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{R}$) and thus they are equal

Comment: @Max Ok, thinking about it from this perspective makes sense. But, just as an aside, aren't all mathematical objects built from set theory anyway?

Comment: Yes in the most common setting

Comment: Ok. Thank you all for the clarification.

Comment: This is basically about whether you think of the integers as really being a subset of the reals (with operations being a separate matter somehow), or merely having some nice embedding mapping them into the reals. In practice no one really cares, in part because mathematicians understand that both approaches are equivalent.

Comment: This question is not well-posed since "practical" doesn't seem to have any real meaning. I've offered an answer at the original post, though, to try to clarify things. I think perhaps it was a little to early to jump the gun and ask a more general question without wrestling with the meaning of the previous question and its answer.

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, I accept that that may be the case. My apologies. It seems that I got carried away with an idea that I was wrestling with.

Comment: I think the concept you're looking for here is "isomorphic", which these two structures are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you want to be really exact, we should think carefully about the condition $x\in\Bbb Z$ for an element $x\in\Bbb R$. Does this mean that you have defined $\Bbb R$ in such a way that $\Bbb Z$ is *actually a subset* of $\Bbb R$? The way it is often done, $\Bbb Z$ only *embeds* into $\Bbb R$ by mapping a number $x\in\Bbb Z$ to the equivalence class of the constant Cauchy sequence $(\frac{x}1,\frac{x}1,\ldots)$. So if you have defined $\Bbb R$ as a set of equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences in $\Bbb Q$, then $\Bbb R$ does not truly contain the set $\Bbb Z$, it *"only"* contains something that is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$ in some very strong ways. If Mathematicians were unable to get over this fact, then we'd have to conclude that $\{ \mathbf{x}\in\Bbb R^n \mid x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\Bbb Z \}=\emptyset$.

## of course, this would be madness.

The fact of the matter is that there is always a strongly intuitive, vastly structure-preserving, injective map $i:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb R$, no matter how you construct $\Bbb R$. This map allows you to think of $i(\Bbb Z)$ as $\Bbb Z$ itself. In fact, it means that you *could* have constructed $\Bbb R$ in such a way that $\Bbb Z$ is *truly* a subset of it. And if you are willing to accept that $\Bbb Z$ is actually a subset of $\Bbb R$, then indeed
$$
\{ x\in\Bbb R^n \mid x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\Bbb Z \} = \Bbb Z^n.
$$

**Proof**. In set theory, we usually define the tuple $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ recursively by the following rules:
\begin{align*}
(x_1,x_2) &:= \{ \{x_1\}, \{x_1,x_2\} \}, \\
(x_1,\ldots,x_k,x_{k+1}) &:= ((x_1,\ldots,x_k),x_{k+1})
\end{align*}
The set $\Bbb Z^n$ simply denotes the set of all tuples $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ with $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\Bbb Z$. Since $\Bbb Z\subseteq \Bbb R$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\{ (x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\Bbb R^n \mid x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\Bbb Z \} 
&= \{ (x_1,\ldots,x_n) \mid x_1,\ldots,x_n\in(\Bbb Z\cap\Bbb R) \} 
\\&= \{ (x_1,\ldots,x_n) \mid x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\Bbb Z \} = \Bbb Z^n.
\end{align*}