# How to prove the existence of the empty set from other axioms in ZFC?

Tags: set-theory

In [another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278863/the-existence-of-the-empty-set-is-an-axiom-of-zfc-or-not), the top answer says:

> If there are sets at all, the axiom of subsets tells us that there is an empty set: If $x$ is a set, then $\{ y∈x ∣ y≠y \}$ is a set, and is empty, since there are no elements $y$ of $x$ for which $y≠y$. The axiom of extensionality then tells us that there is only one such empty set.”

I am having trouble understanding the move from 'there exists a set $x$' to '$\{ y∈x ∣ y≠y \}$ is a set'. Why is it the case that there is a subset of $x$, $y$, such that $y$ is distinct from itself?

I may be missing something basic here.

Comment: The Axiom Schema of Separation says (roughly) that if $\phi$ is a formula for sets, and $x$ is a set, the there is a set whose elements are precisely the $y\in x$ for which $\phi(y)$ is true. So if $\phi$ is the formula $y\neq y$ then $\{y\in x\mid \phi(y)\}$ is a set.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That can be an answer.

Comment: +Some set exists either because model theory defines domains of discourse to be non-empty, or because of the axiom of infinity, or by adding an axiom asserting the existence of some set.

Comment: Nobody said "there is a subset of $x$, $y$, such that $y$ is distinct from itself." Read the passge you quoted; that's not what it says.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but it seems what you're missing is an understanding of what the notation $\{ y∈x ∣ y≠y \}$ means.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you, that's extremely helpful. So the proof rests on y≠y counting as a formula and the Axiom Schema of Separation.

Comment: @bof That may be true--what's the right way to understand the notation then?

Comment: @YV1999 The problem with your interpretation "... there is a subset of $x$, $y$, such that $y$ is distinct from itself?" of $\ \{y\in x\,|\,y\ne y\}\ $ is in misidentifying a putative element $\ y\ $ of that subset of $\ x\ $ with the subset itself.  A correct statement would be "...there is a subset of $\ x\ $ comprising those elements $\ y\ $ of $\ x\ $ which are distinct from themselves.

Comment: @YV1999 And of course, nothing is distinct from itself, so this subset of $x$ is empty.